# My husband did not divorce me, but says he did in court; what is my marital status?

Tags: talaq, husband-wife

I'm separated from my husband since 12 years ago, he did not divorce me but in the court he said in front of the judge: "I have divorced her but she is denying it".

- What is my status in Islam?
- What about his intentions or his words?

Answer (score 1):

You must pay attention that doing divorce is related to some specific conditions. Of course I saw you said: in the court he said in front of the judge: "I have divorced her but she is denying it". In order to survey the mentioned issue from an angle as a condition of divorce,  it could be declared that " Divorce contract must be recited with the correct Arabic words in a way such that two just men (as witness) listen to it. consequently it doesn't seem to be a credit divorce, since he has not observed its conditions completely.

Eventually you'd better refer to Islamic court to solve it. Since it could be surveyed from another angle as well (that it is a long time that you are separated from each other or perhaps he has left you for a long time ...). Good luck.

---

**Reference:**

- [www.islamquest.net](http://www.islamquest.net/fa/archive/question/fa8230)

Comment: Not all divorces are recited in Arabic in the Islamic world.